# Scrapy Pipelines not getting detected

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to implement Files pipeline and the only documentation I found is [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/kzGHFjXywuY/O6PIhoT3thsJ)
I downloaded the files.py and this is my directory hierarchy:

```
getit(my scrapy project)

    - files -> files.py ( my pipeline)
    - settings.py
    - spiders -> mySpider
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'getit.files.FilesPipeline'}
FILES_STORE ='/home/kidd0/getit/downloads'
```

When I crawl I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Error loading object 'getit.files.FilesPipeline': No module named files
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong. Its my 1st week of python programming and I have realised that its not able to find that class. I have even tried to compile it to .pyc but no luck. Is there some way to create modules that I am overlooking. Kindly help.

Comment: does your `files/` directory contain an (empty) `__init__.py` file? otherwise Python import won't consider it as a module. Also, if you do that, you'll need something like `ITEM_PIPELINES = {'getit.files.files.FilesPipeline': 500}` (yes, 2 `files`) .See [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#item-pipelines)

Comment: @pault: Oh.. I just created it, but the same error. I guess I should upgrade my scrapy Since .20 has support for filesPipeline by default